# FRM-40735: When button pressed trigger raised unhandled exception ORA-06502

Tags: sql, forms, oracle, plsql

```
if :entete.carto = 'O' then
    declare
        c_criteres varchar2(240);
    BEGIN
        go_item(:ENTETE.CURRENT_ITEM_PRECEDENT);
        IF :ENTETE.LOX_BE='PTV' THEN
            :global.type_lancement := 'GEOCOD';
            c_criteres := '-jar '|| :entete.empl_jar||'geocodeur.jar '
                                        || :entete.c_user || ' '
                                        || :entete.c_passe || ' '
                                        || :global.connection_string || ' '
                                        || '1 ' -- ecrire dans un fichier en sortie
                                        || '1 ' -- debug
                                        || '1' /*geocod cf*/ || ' '
                                        || :global.chemin_cr || ' '
                                        || :global.utilisateur;
            lancer_executable('javaw',:entete.c_user,:entete.c_passe,
                            :entete.c_noeud,:entete.c_os,'1',c_criteres);
        END IF;
        enter_query;
    END;
end if;
```

can someone advise about the reason for such an error?
I am new to oracle forms and need to figure out why this issue is occuring in order to resolve it.

thank you

Comment: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error - check that your fields data type the same as values, which you put in it
http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora06502.php

Comment: Can you post your code for lancer_executable()?

Comment: I would comment-out the call to `lancer_executable` first to check whether the exception is being raised by this code, or by the call to the procedure. Perhaps the value being assigned to `c_criteres` is longer than 240 characters.

Comment: the issue was solved. it was with the c_criteres that is longer than 240. thank you all

Answer (score 3):

Usually this error is because you are trying to assign a value to a variable or field that is not to big enough. Example

```
v_name VARCHAR2(5);
```

After you try to:

```
 v_name := 'ABCDEFGHIJK';
```

The variable's length is 5 and you try to assign a string with 10 characters.

Hope it helps.